# Get URI of an mp3 file

Tags: android, android-intent

I know this question has been asked multiple number of times. I,basically,am trying to select an mp3 file from SD card memory or phone memory. However,the mp3 files are not selectable when i try it on my device. When i use a third party app like File Manager to select the mp3, it works. Is this some issue with the lollipop file manager or am i doing it wrong?

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("audio/mp3");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Music File"), 200);
        }
    });



@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {


            if (resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                if (reqCode == 200) {
                    Uri audioFileUri = data.getData();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), audioFileUri.getPath().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
               }
    }
```

EDIT:

What i mean by not selectable(ex:the mp3 file below is JustinTimberlake) is:
[image]

Comment: What does "the mp3 files are not selectable when i try it on my device" mean? "I,basically,am trying to select an mp3 file from SD card memory or phone memory" -- no, you are not. There is no requirement that the `Uri` that you get back from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` points to a file.

Comment: Check out the edit, please.

Comment: Hmmm... do you have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions?

Comment: i added these two permissions: 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> but the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

The mime type for mp3 is `audio/mpeg`.
You can use

```
intent.setType("audio/mpeg");
```

or

```
String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("mp3");
intent.setType(mimeType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent automatic_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  automatic_intent.setType("audio/mpeg");